# Why Does SQL return the correct info but QueryBuilder / DQL returns NULL for joined table

Tags: sql, symfony, join, doctrine-orm, dql

I have 2 statements that I believe are identical:

SQL Version:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

$RAW_QUERY = 'SELECT *
              FROM licences
              JOIN users ON licences.user_id=users.id
              WHERE licences.type=:licenceType
              AND licences.created_at BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate';

$statement = $em->getConnection()->prepare($RAW_QUERY);

// Set parameters
$statement->bindValue('licenceType', $licenceType);
$statement->bindValue('startDate', $startDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
$statement->bindValue('endDate', $endDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
$statement->execute();

$licences = $statement->fetchAll();

foreach ($licences as $licence) {
    dump($licence);
}
die;
```

DQL / Query Builder Version:

```
$licences = $this->get('em')->getRepository(Licence::class)->createQueryBuilder('l')
    ->join('l.user', 'u')
    ->where('l.type = :type')
    ->andwhere('l.createdAt BETWEEN :start AND :end')
    ->setParameter('type', $licenceType)
    ->setParameter('start', $startDate)
    ->setParameter('end', $endDate);

$licences = $licences->getQuery()->getResult();
foreach ($licences as $licence) {
    dump($licence);
}
die;
```

However the SQL version returns actual info from the user table whereas in the DQL version it is all NULL. I have tried experimenting with the DQl (especially the ->join but to no avail). Any help much appreciated!

Comment: you can do `$licences->getQuery()->getDQL()` to show the generated DQL and `$licences->getQuery()->getSQL()` to show the generated SQL for comparison.

Comment: I know I can get the SQL from DQL but you are saying I can get DQL from SQL?

Comment: No the query builder first parses every input to DQL, thats why its faster to use DQL directly AND then it creates SQL From the DQL. Regarding the problem my  guess would be that `$startDate` and `$endDate` are not matching the expected format and thats why it is always advised to provide the Doctrine property metadata `ORM\Column` etc...

Comment: `->join('l.user', 'u')` shoud that not be plural `->join('l.users', 'u')`?